# Installshield 2010 - On upgrade check its already upgraded to certain version

Tags: installshield-2010

I'm currently updating my installer (Basic MSI) for a program to v5.00.0000. I need InstallShield to check that if it's an upgrade, it must be on at least 4.00.0034.

> So if it's not previously installed, it installs ok.
>
> If it's on 4.00.0020, it must return a message to say please upgrade to v4.00.0034 first.

Thanks,
Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the ISPreventDowngrades action and the major upgrade item that finds newer versions, or read up on how to prevent downgrades. You can then copy this approach, tweaking it to instead find and error out on ones less than 4.0.34.